# JNA how to pass String[] from Java to C code

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jna

I have an issue. I first need to understand how to pass a 'String[] contentsStatic'. I can see in the JNA documentation that the String[] should map to Char**. I am not sure how to map this on the Java side. In my particular implementation I am not even sure if this would actually work, because the C code I am trying to use is MatLab, so in the C code it is expecting a 'const emxArray_char_T *contentsStatic. I do not know what this is.

This is the C side:

```
Initialise(const emxArray_char_T *contentsStatic, const
                    emxArray_char_T *contentsDynamic, int b_phoneAngleDeg, double
                            b_stepCalibrationOffset, int b_initialFloorNumber, int
                            b_initialPointingAngleDeg, int b_initialAlignmentMode, bool *mapStatus, bool
  *paramStatus);
```

The Java Side is:

```
initialise(String[] contentsStatic,
                                String[] contentsDynamic,
                                int phoneRelativeToBodyDegree,
                                double initialStepCalibrationOffset, 
                                int startingFloorID,
                                LatLng startingLatLong,
                                double startingAccuracy,
                                boolean _CDontActuallyUse,
                                int phoneOrientation,
                                int phoneOrientationUse,
                                boolean magntometerValid
                                )
```

Mapping method for reference:

```
private struct MatWrap
{
    var MatString: MatString
    private var string_size_array_to_pass: [Int32]
    private var string_bytes_int8: [Int8]

    init(string: String)
    {
        let string_size = MatWrap.getSize(string: string)

        self.string_bytes_int8 = MatWrap.getInt8Array(string: string)
        self.string_size_array_to_pass = MatWrap.getSizeArray(size: string_size)

        self.MatString = MatWrap.makeMatString(
            data: &self.string_bytes_int8,
            size: &self.string_size_array_to_pass,
            allocatedSize: string_size
        )
    }

    private static func getInt8Array(string: String) -> [Int8] {
        let data = string.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)!
        let bytes = [UInt8](data)
        let bytes_int8 = bytes.map{Int8($0)}
        return bytes_int8
    }

    private static func getSize(string: String) -> Int32 {
        return Int32(string.lengthOfBytes(using: .ascii))
    }

    private static func getSizeArray(size: Int32) -> [Int32] {
        return [1, size]
    }

    private static func makeMatString(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, size: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, allocatedSize: Int32) -> MatString {
        return MatString(data: data, size: size, allocatedSize: allocatedSize, numDimensions: 1, canFreeData: false)
    }
}
```

The Method used to prepare the joined String[] to pass:

```
allFloorsDynamic_wrappedMatString =  MatWrap(string: contentsDynamic.joined())
```

Comment: What does the native API say the array of strings should look like?   `char *` is (in C) a null terminated array of characters.  But to have an array of strings, you would have to have some sort of information on how to iterate the array.  Is it expecting constant length character arrays?  A set of null-delimited strings?   We can't help you without more information about the native method as described in its API.

Comment: @DanielWiddis OK so please correct me if i don't understand you correctly, so when you say the Native API, I don't really have access to much, this C code was a custom piece of code written originally to work with IOS, it is C from MatLab and the only real documentation is the Swift wrapper which i am trying to replicate for Android, this is not the easiest process for me to do right now. So are you recommending i need to speak with the original C coders, or is there another way i can find this info?

Comment: You need to not guess when you see "array" and "char" that you need a string array.  You know `String[]` maps to `char **` but there is no `char **` in the native code you're mapping, so that's the wrong type to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking how to pass a `String[]` but that's not what the native function is expecting.

Looking at [the Matlab docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help//coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html), `emxArray_char_T` is a structure:

```
struct emxArray_char_T
{
   char * str;
   int size;
};
```

Further, reading the documents, you can see this description of the API:

> The code generator produces C/C++ array definitions that depend on the
>   array element type and whether the array uses static or dynamic memory
>   allocation. The two kinds of memory allocation for an array require
>   two different implementations:
>
> - For an array whose size is bounded within a predefined threshold, the
>     generated C/C++ definition consists of a pointer to memory and an
>     integer that stores the total number of array elements, the array
>     size. The memory for this array comes from the program stack and is
>     statically allocated.
> - For an array whose size is unknown and unbounded at compile time, or
>     whose bound exceeds a predefined threshold, the generated C/C++
>     definition consists of a data structure called an emxArray. When an
>     emxArray is created, intermediate storage bounds are set based on the
>     current array size. During program execution, as intermediate storage
>     bounds are exceeded, the generated code appropriates additional memory
>     space from the heap and adds it to the emxArray storage. The memory
>     for this array is dynamically allocated.

For the case where you are passing `const` values to the native side, you can use the statically allocated version.  However, here you run into a limitation of JNA: the size of arrays must be known when you define the structure.  So to use a structure you'd have to do it like this:

```
@FieldOrder ({"str", "size"})
class emxArray_char_T_3 extends Structure {
    public String[] strArray = new String[3];
    public int size = 3;
}
```

You would define this and then set the 3 `strArray` elements.  You could do a similar array for different sizes.

However, it looks like MATLAB has helper functions for creating this array, such as [`emxCreateWrapper_char_T`](https://www.mathworks.com/help//coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html#mw_f9b29605-2fde-414a-8c55-e430ecde5bee).  You may want to figure out how to use those.

Further digging into the docs, [they say](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/mapping-matlab-types-to-cc-types.html#mw_82e983fa-328b-4c16-baec-ea15115a8a16):

> If you are not using dynamic memory allocation, arrays in structures
>   translate into single-dimension arrays, not pointers.

This is a challenge for strings, which are variable length arrays, and a typical `String[]` mapping for other language would be an array of pointers to strings elsewhere.   This implies that to directly use the existing structures with the `const` type you would have to have constant-length character arrays defined for your strings.

Looking at the syntax for the string arrays that you've added with the edit, it still looks like you have to pass a single string, but the notation `joined` implies that it expects some sort of delimited notation.  Again, this is something you'll have to search the API to find exactly what the delimiter is!

Comment: Ok i see i create the Struct and pass as that, using the Structure annotations i have used before. That has really been a fantastic help. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies @DanielWiddis Got a little confused over this one, so i have a string[] which for arguments sake is {"john", "Paul", "James"} in Java and as you stated this we can map as your class emx_Array_Char_T which takes a String and a Size, how do i represent the String array i have as a String to pass to the new Class? Hope that makes sense? Thanks

Comment: My apologies, I made my own assumptions.  I updated my answer. You probably need to search for some examples, though.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWiddis I will have a look at that now. Cheers

Comment: Just to let you know if it makes any difference, within the C header file in the other wrapper i can see the struct is defined as:                                         struct emxArray_char_T
{
  char *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  bool canFreeData;
};  but you are right it is being received in the c file as a const.

Comment: Yep, I saw that version but I think that's the "dynamic" one while the one I posted is static.   There are helper classes to create the structures that I think you'll want to use, but the only ones I saw were for a single string, or an array of values.  I can't find any "array of strings" ones.  It might not be possible, actually.

Comment: You might try passing a single string and then using `split()` to turn it into an array internally.

Comment: Thank you for that I do really appreciate your support on this. I will have to have a look at the suggestions and see if i can make any headway this evening. If it seems that we hit the limitations of JNA for this, do you think I will then have to look at JNI to get the job done?

Comment: JNI won't help you in this one any more than JNA will.  The fact is if the API doesn't tell you how to feed a string array into matlab from C, you're stuck either way.  And that appears to be the situation.

Comment: I will just add a method to the question, i have found, deep in the wrapper code MatString maps exactly to the emxArray_char_T struct do you think this is the way it gets mapped? There must be a way, this is in swift obviously but do you think there would be a way i can replicate this in Java, the issue i keep finding is swift is based on Objective C so the mapping is a lot easier with the pass by reference.

Comment: That's still just the string.  You could replicate any particular pass by reference format easily in JNA if you knew exactly what format Matlab expects. But that's the problem here, there is no documentation on passing a string array via C methods.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to have a good look into what I can do tomorrow. Appreciate the help and advice as always.

Comment: I have created a new question as i have come up against a further issue, i have really appreciated your advice on this, here is a link if you have the time and inclination that would be very helpful. Thanks Daniel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785423/jna-passing-the-equivalent-of-swift-pointer-from-java-android-to-c

Comment: I have also added to the question the method i think used by the Swift side to prepare the string to pass to the Matlab C code, what do you think? would that make sense, or will we still struggle? Even when i join the String [] i am not sure how i would implement that MatWrap class in Java? If in your more experienced opinion you think this is possible i will devote some time to trying to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: ok final question if i am passing this structure as a string and size both of which are pointers. i.e.struct emxArray_char_T
{
  char *data;
  int *size;
}; How do you pass a pointer within a structure? Thanks

Comment: You just pass the pointer. If it's a String, JNA takes care of allocating the memory and passing the pointer to the null terminated array of characters for you so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thanks looks good on that, but i would love your expert opinion on this, sending the int[] to the struct, we definitely send a pointer to a string array even though in the cstruct it looks is *size its [1, size] if your around would love some advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821053/confirmation-i-am-sending-the-pointer-to-int-correctly-in-java-jna