# JNA passing the equivalent of swift pointer from Java Android to C

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, jna

I am a little stuck trying to pass an implementation of this Swift code in Java, to C. Would appreciate any advice i am using JNA to integrate between the Java and Matlab generated C code.

This is the Swift call:

```
GetResult(uptime, &result_out)
```

It Maps to the C code:

```
void GetResult(double time, Result_t *Result)
```

The C struct Result_t is too big for here, however it is a combination of double's and int's.

I understand &result_out is a swift pointer? How is it best to go about implementing the equivalent of the Swift pointer in Java and then be able to pass it to C that is expecting a pointer to the Result_t which as i mentioned is a structure made up of doubles and ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` denotes the memory address of a variable.  In this case, it means the memory address of the `Result` structure.

In C you can see the `*` symbol used to denote the same thing: the variable to be passed as the second argument is the reference/memory address of the underlying data.

These often appear in pairs: if you have a variable `foo` defined you can easily pass `&foo` to any method expecting the pointer to `foo`, while the method itself uses the `*` notation to let you know it requires that pointer.

For many JNA structures you need to pay close attention to these symbols.  Knowing whether to pass an `int` or `IntByReference`, for example, is key.  But fortunately (for ease of writing code, or unfortunately for consistency) the behavior of the JNA `Structure` class is different.  The bottom line is that, by default, when a `Structure` is included as an argument to a method/function (the most common application) the pointer, or `ByReference` version of the structure is used.  So in this particular case, assuming you have mapped a `class Result extends Structure` with all the information, you can simply pass `result` where `result = new Result();`.

There are ways to use `ByReference` and `ByValue` to override this default behavior but that's beyond the scope of your question.