# Confirmation I am sending the pointer to int[] correctly in Java JNA

Tags: java, android, c, jna

I am passing a pointer to an int[] as here, which is in my structure/class in java see below:

```
        int[] initialDynamicSize = new int[]{1, initialDynamicAllocatedSize};
        int[] allFloorsSize = new int[]{1, allFloorsAllocatedSize};

        Pointer PTRinitialDynamicSize = new Memory(2*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE));
        PTRinitialDynamicSize.setInt(0*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),1);
        PTRinitialDynamicSize.setInt(1*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),initialDynamicAllocatedSize);

        Pointer PTRallFloorsSize = new Memory(2*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE));
        PTRinitialDynamicSize.setInt(0*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),1);
        PTRallFloorsSize.setInt(1*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),allFloorsAllocatedSize);
```

The structure looks like this:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "str", "size", "allocatedSize", "numDimensions", "canFreeData"})
public class test extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{


    public Pointer str;
    //private int numVals;
    public Pointer size;
    public int allocatedSize;
    public int numDimensions;
    public boolean canFreeData;

    //Static
    public test(Pointer str, Pointer size) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
    }

    //Dynamic
    public test(Pointer str, Pointer size, int allocatedSize, int numDimensions, boolean canFreeData) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
        this.allocatedSize = allocatedSize;
        this.numDimensions = numDimensions;
        this.canFreeData = canFreeData;
    }

    public test() {
    }
}
```

I am getting errors back from my C code, i want to rule out any errors with this code. the C code struct that receives the data is:

```
struct emxArray_char_T
{
  char *data;
  int *size; // This is the string array that i am sending
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  bool canFreeData;
};
```

This is a MatLab Struct https://uk.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html#mw_0cae9a4a-b74d-43f9-aae0-ed192db73d22

Comment: I'm not seeing any `C` code here.

Comment: Added the c struct if helpful

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know what the errors you are getting back are, to focus the review. Otherwise you're asking us to mentally compile and run your code. :)

Comment: It would also be helpful to point us to the documentation for the C structure. You haven't even given us its name so we can search it.  Only because I have answered previous questions from you on Matlab do I have a hint what you're asking.  Please edit your question with at least a link to the API/documentation telling you about this structure.  If you know the `int[]` will always have 2 elements it's far easier to specify that in the structure.  You can also use `Pointer.write()` with integer array to simplify your code, and save your native size of integer to a temp variable as well.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Struggling to get Logging out of the native code, the __android_log_print does not seem to want to work for me no matter what configurations i use! Joy!, the backtrace from ADB just tells me its a rtDynamicBoundError, but i don't know what kind i will let you know more if i can get some helpful logging out. That was really why i was asking if the implementation in general looks like it should work because i can't get any feedback right at this minute. I will keep you posted. Thanks as always.

Comment: Missed the top line off the struct apologies it is the emxArray_char_T I will add that to the Question and the link.